# How to use Laravel to develop mobile applications' Back-ends (iOS and Android)? Any Tutorial?

Tags: android, ios, laravel, laravel-5

We have seen Laravel has facilitated web development. But I wonder there is any tutorial to help us develop Mobile Applications' back-ends (iOS and Android) using Laravel?

Comment: i think you are new to stackoverflow community. Kindly add some detail to your question and be more specific. You have got negative votes because of these issues. And kindly read this [how to write good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

You can write backend APIs in Laravel. And [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/) is a good lightweight micro framework by Laravel for writing APIs. All you need is a REST-ful API to get you going. Have look at [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785) to get you started.